# Updating ILO on HP DL380 G7 fails due to firmware version gap

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I tried updating several HP Proliant DL380 G7 ILOs today to firmware version 1.50.
Some had 1.15, some had 1.26. Those with the older revision refused to accept the firmware blob, the newer ones did update successfully.

Is this behaviour expected or documented somewhere?

Updating to 1.50 via 1.26 is acceptable, I do wonder why this happens though.

Comment: It happens because the iLO 1.50 firmware has a new signature mechanism, and only 1.20 and later have the ability to check the signature. You'll notice the images are slightly larger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You typically need to update to ILO3 version *1.28* and *then* move to version *1.50*.

As you can can see below, I keep both ILO versions handy on my jump server, just in case I encounter an ILO3 with a <1.20 firmware version.

[image]

In the ILO firmware package README file:

> PREREQUISITE:  iLO 3 v1.20 BUILD DATE:  8/20/2012 EFFECTIVE DATE: 
>   9/24/2012 DESCRIPTION:   Firmware for the Hewlett-Packard
>                  Integrated Lights-Out 3 Management Controller
>
> LAST RECOMMENDED OR CRITICAL VERSION: 1.28
>
> PREVIOUS VERSION: 1.28 UPGRADE REQUIREMENTS:
>
> RECOMMENDED: Includes new enhancements, features, and/or minor bug
>   fixes.
>
> FIRMWARE DEPENDENCY: iLO 3 should be upgraded to v1.20 before
>   upgrading to this version.